# Since shows continuity and is it used only in perfect continuous tense?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

> 1.Two hours have passed **since** he fell asleep.
>   2. He has eaten nothing **since** yesterday.

Regarding the usage of **since**, as far as  I know below are the only points:

1. It shows the continuity of the task.
2. It is used in the **perfect continuous tenses**.
3. It is used in the form : **has/have/had  been + first form of verb + ing + since**.

My query is :

1. Neither of the above sentence is in perfect continuous tense but still since has been used there?

Suggestions please.  Please let me know if I am missing any rule of **since**.

Comment: No, it's *not* as mentioned in #3. For 'since', it's used to denote *one starting point* **till** now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Michael Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Swan_(writer))'s Practical English Usage, Unit 522,

> In sentences with **since** (referring to time) we normally use present perfect and past perfect tenses in the main clause.
> "*I've known her since 1980*"
>
> ... However, present and past tenses are also occasionally found, especially in sentences about changes.
> "*You're looking much better since your operation*"

Thus, your rules no. 2 and 3 [hold no water](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-water). Swan's book has a nice index at the end that can direct you to a number of units concerning **since** (522, 208, 411.6, 458.5, 72). Only unit 458.5 concerns the use of **since** with present perfect progressive. You might find that book very useful.